# ¿Por qué no se muestra la imagen usando p:graphicImage?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en una columna de un `p:datatable`, pero no me es posible. El servidor me dice:

> com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.logMissingResource
>   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, imgproductos/5135846.png.

Y lo he definido de la siguiente manera:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbproducto" var="producto" value="#{productoBean.listProductos}" widgetVar="wgtable"
    filteredValue="#{productoBean.filtrolistProductos}" 
    style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px" rowKey="#{producto.idproductos}"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{productoBean.producto}" 
    paginator="true"  paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,30" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250"
    emptyMessage="No se Encontraron Productos...">
    <p:column headerText="Imagen">
        <p:graphicImage  value="#{FacesContext.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()}/#{producto.codigobarras}.png"
            alt="sin imagen" width="90" height="90"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Codigo de Barras">
        <h:outputText value="#{producto.codigobarras}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column filterBy="#{producto.descripcion}" headerText="Descripcion" width="350">
        <h:outputText value="#{producto.descripcion}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="">
        <p:commandButton value="Añadir Imagen" onclick="PF('dialogoimgproducto').show()"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises lo siguiente: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-graphicimage-example/ para la versión 2 de JSF (PrimeFaces se basa en el trabajo de JSF) y este link http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1065197 para que entiendas mejor como se utiliza el atributo `library`.

Answer (score 4):

Resulta que ya encontre el por que no se me mostraban las imagenes, esto se debe aque las imagenes deben estar en la carpeta "resources" (si no la tienes creala) y dentro de ella agregar las carpetas según tu necesidad. Para usarlo en el componente quedaria asi:

```
 <p:graphicImage value="#{FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()}/resources/img/img1.jpg"/>
```

y LISTO.

Comment: O simplemente usabas `name`. Al parecer no viste ninguno de los links que coloqué en el comentario a la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes razon. Pero mil gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada. Por favor considera [aceptar esta respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227) en cuanto puedas :)